# How can I obtain ID's from friends that I invited from facebook IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to know who accepted my app request or invite to join my app.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make a GraphPath request of your friends list using `/me/friends?fields=installed` , you'll get back a dictionary with a key named "installed", and the value "True", if that friend has your app. If they don't have your app, then the "installed" key won't even be there, and you'll just get the friend's regular info.

So basically, make that GraphPath request, and then check to is if an "installed" key exists in the dictionary that it returns. If it does, they have it.